# How to config multiple file folder in InternalResourceViewResolver Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I had a program crash

It does not work

```
Example: <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view1/"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view2/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Why you have 2 prefixes?

Comment: i want make two folder to store file  difference jsp

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use one prefix `/WEB-INF/`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And call you JSP with secondary prefix as `/view2/second.jsp` or `/view1/first.jsp`